# ¿Cómo realizar regresiones tomando fija la variable dependiente y que cambie solo la variable dependiente?

Tags: r, rstudio

¿Cómo realizar regresiones tomando fija la variable dependiente y que cambie solo la variable dependiente?, es decir que el data frame es algo como

```
year  a b c d..... z
1
2
3
4
```

Necesito que la variable dependiente siempre sea `a` pero la independiente sea `b`, luego `c` y así sucesivamente y que luego me de el resultado en una lista de las variables dependendientes que fueron significativas, por ejemplo:

```
b
c
h
```

Intenté hacer lo siguiente

```
for (i in 1:40) {

  modelo_prueba <- lm(data = ds, formula = a ~ ds[ ,i]) 
  print(summary(modelo_prueba))

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definir la formula así: `a ~ ds[ ,i]` es sintácticamente válido, pero el problema, que en el contexto de evaluación del modelo lineal, no existe ni el objeto `i` ni el objeto `ds`.

Puedes definir la formula de manera dinámica con cada iteración como una simple cadena y luego transformarla en una formula real mediante [`as_formula()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/formula):

```
modelos <- list()
var_dep <- "a"
var_ind <- colnames(data)[colnames(data) != var_dep]
columnas_a_eliminar <- vector()
for (var in var_ind) {
  formula <- as.formula(paste(var_dep, "~ ", var))
  fit <- lm(data = data, formula = formula) 
  if (summary(fit)$coefficients[2,4] > 0.05)
    columnas_a_eliminar <- c(columnas_a_eliminar, var)
}

if (length(columnas_a_eliminar)>0)
  data <- data[, !(colnames(data) %in% columnas_a_eliminar),  drop = FALSE]
```

En el ejemplo, definimos cual es `var_dep` y luego las variables independientes, tomando todas las columnas menos la de la variable dependiente, en tu caso, tendrías (imagino) quitar la columna `year` también. Luego iteramos por los nombres de cada variable independiente, generamos una cadena para la formula y la transformamos en tal.

Comment: Se puede en ese mismo for pedir que sí el p valor de la variable independiente es mayora 0.05 quite esa **var_ind** de **data** ?

Comment: @kev, si se puede, solo hay que buscar el  `p.value` del modelo y verificarlo. Revisa mi última edición.

Comment: no me corre el segundo if. Intenté lo siguiente                         
 du <- data.frame()                                                                                                                               
 for (i in columnas_a_dejar) {
  du = ds[ ,i]
}

Comment: ¿Para que un for? ya tienes un vector con las columnas que quieres, esto debería funcionar:  `ds[, columnas_a_dejar]`

Comment: Ahora funciona perfecto. Muchas Gracias @Patricio Moracho